# Is there a way to mark a question as duplicate if the duplicate exists in another community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently I came across a question on SO,

*[Access Printer using SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59064649/access-printer-using-sql-server-stored-procedure)*

which had a possible duplicate on dba.stackexchange:

*[Is there an elegant way to send a query directly to a physical printer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-send-a-query-directly-to-a-physical-printer)*

Is there a way to mark the first question on SO as a duplicate of the the second question on DBA.Stackexchange? If there isn't can this be a new feature?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/476201

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates ... The irony.